# How to uninstall app Nimble keyboard

Tags: applications, keyboard

I installed this myself. But, the app doesn't appear in list of all apps. Tried to search, but it's nowhere to be found! How can I get rid of this very annoying app?

Comment: Open the app in play store and uninstall

Comment: Did OP download the app from Google Play?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you downloaded your file. I just installed this keyboard from Google Play and I'm able to find it on the drawer and in the app list.  You probably got it from a third party market which may contains malwares. I can confirm its annoyance due to multiple ads though.
[image]
[image]

Was also able to delete it. 
[image]